# Alternative to nvidia-settings GpuPowerMizerMode in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, nvidia, power-mgmt

We have a Ubuntu 20.04 server with Nvidia GPUs and want to change the **Power Mode** / `GpuPowerMizerMode` to `Prefer Maximum Performance`.

One way to do this is

```
nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:0]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1"
```

However, that would require an X session with access to the respective GPU; editing `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` would not work for the same reason.

Is there another way to read and set the `GpuPowerMizerMode` of a Nvidia GPU in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this comment](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-settings-unable-to-init-server/54006/4), you need to have a dummy X server running. Here is how I've been able to accomplish this in Ubuntu 20.04.

1. Install the necessary packages:

```
sudo apt install xorg
```

2. Run `nvidia-xconfig`:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a
```

3. Edit `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` and add:

```
allowed_users=anybody
```

4. Start the X server:

```
startx
```

5. In another terminal, run `nvidia-settings`:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:0]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1"
```

It happily replies with:

```
Attribute 'GPUPowerMizerMode' (orion:0[gpu:0]) assigned value 1.
```

Now the Performance State of my GPU stays at P2.

Answer (score 2):

this is how i solved it on my machines (headless servers, using SSH);

make sure tmux is installed, or use SCREEN

```
tmux new-session -s [your new session's name here]

sudo ls 

sudo X :0 &

export DISPLAY=:0

nvidia-settings -a [whatever commands you want to use]
nvidia-settings -a [whatever commands you want to use]
nvidia-settings -a [whatever commands you want to use]
```